# JavaScript: fields or properties

Tags: javascript, properties, field

In every JavaScript tutorial that I have looked there is something mentioned about a property of an object. But why do they call it a property? e.g. constructor property, `var a = function{this.b}` where `b` is again called property. As far as I know properties have getter and/or setter, so those one should be called field, shouldn't they?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some browser vendor have implemented getters/setters for JavaScript properties.

FF and Webkit has `__defineGetter__`and `__defineSetter__` implemented for DOM objects and get and set for Object's which is outside of the ECMA specification. However both and also IE 8+ has the `Object.defineProperty` (from the ECMA specification). Read about it [here](http://www.robertnyman.com/javascript/javascript-getters-setters.html)

As for you original question, I would say that the reason it's called property in JavaScript is that it's a dynamic language and the basic markup uses only properties and local var's. Since everything is bound to a specific scope-hierarchy all you have is different tree-branches on each level. And Douglas Croockford named them properties :)

Comment: Ok. 10x. It seems that there are some getter and setter [ECMA](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) 8.6.1.

Comment: There's also references to the "fields" word (and also "private fields") in the class fields declarations ECMAScript proposal (currently Stage 3 in the TC39 process) https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields

Answer (score 1):

It's like with `hash`, `map`, `dictionary` and `associative array`; different languages like to call them different things. Terminology (unfortunately) isn't 100% transferable between programming languages.

Comment: Properties allow you to change how the underlying data is both set and retrieved while fields are just variables on an object. Since Object.defineProperty allows you to change this behavior they are properties. If there wasn't a mechanism allowing to you change how the data was set or retrieved they would be fields.