# How to create a type excluding instance methods from a class in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given a class, containing both properties and methods, I'd like to derive a type that just contains its properties.

For example, if I define a class as follow:

```
class MyObject {

  constructor(public prop1: string, public prop2: number) {}

  instanceMethod() { ... }
}
```

I'd like to have a type, say `MyObjectConstructor` that would be like this:

```
type MyObjectConstructor = {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: number;
}
```

I know I can use the built-in type `Pick` and manually select the keys I want by name, but I don't want to have to repeat the keys all over, and have to change them every time I add new properties to my class.

Is there a way to define a generic type `ConstructorType<T>`that only returns the properties of a class in typescript ?

Comment: what you basically want is some form of conversion between a function's parameters and an object where the keys are parameter names and values are parameter types. I hate to say this, but there isn't a straight fix for your problem. everything you find will feel like a "hack"

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I've found a way to exclude all properties that match a given type, thanks to this article: https://medium.com/dailyjs/typescript-create-a-condition-based-subset-types-9d902cea5b8c

I made a few adaptations, but here is the details:

```js
// 1 Transform the type to flag all the undesired keys as 'never'
type FlagExcludedType<Base, Type> = { [Key in keyof Base]: Base[Key] extends Type ? never : Key };
    
// 2 Get the keys that are not flagged as 'never'
type AllowedNames<Base, Type> = FlagExcludedType<Base, Type>[keyof Base];
    
// 3 Use this with a simple Pick to get the right interface, excluding the undesired type
type OmitType<Base, Type> = Pick<Base, AllowedNames<Base, Type>>;
    
// 4 Exclude the Function type to only get properties
type ConstructorType<T> = OmitType<T, Function>;
```

[Try It](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%201%20Transform%20the%20type%20to%20flag%20all%20the%20undesired%20keys%20as%20%27never%27%0D%0Atype%20FlagExcludedType%3CBase%2C%20Type%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BKey%20in%20keyof%20Base%5D%3A%20Base%5BKey%5D%20extends%20Type%20%3F%20never%20%3A%20Key%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%202%20Get%20the%20keys%20that%20are%20not%20flagged%20as%20%27never%27%0D%0Atype%20AllowedNames%3CBase%2C%20Type%3E%20%3D%20FlagExcludedType%3CBase%2C%20Type%3E%5Bkeyof%20Base%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%203%20Use%20this%20with%20a%20simple%20Pick%20to%20get%20the%20right%20interface%2C%20excluding%20the%20undesired%20type%0D%0Atype%20OmitType%3CBase%2C%20Type%3E%20%3D%20Pick%3CBase%2C%20AllowedNames%3CBase%2C%20Type%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%204%20Exclude%20the%20Function%20type%20to%20only%20get%20properties%0D%0Atype%20ConstructorType%3CT%3E%20%3D%20OmitType%3CT%2C%20Function%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyObject%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor(public%20prop1%3A%20string%2C%20public%20prop2%3A%20number)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20instanceMethod()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%27this%20does%20nothing%27)%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20MyObjectConstructor%20%3D%20ConstructorType%3CMyObject%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A)

There might be a simpler way, I've tried playing with `ConstructorParameters` and defining a constructor signature but without results.

**Update**

Found an equivalent while browsing the typescript documentation here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types

```js
type NonFunctionPropertyNames<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K;
}[keyof T];
type NonFunctionProperties<T> = Pick<T, NonFunctionPropertyNames<T>>;
```

It's a bit less verbose since the omitted type is not generic, but it's the same idea.

Comment: although more verbose than the other suggested answer, this does seem to work for me, thank you & yay! https://gist.github.com/raould/645c93035adfd479b1801d2c539ee55e

Comment: The problem with this answer is that thought it excludes methods, it also excludes function properties, which is problematic.  Unfortunately, it seems like Typescript doesn't seem to provide a way to differentiate between methods and function properties at the moment, though VSCode hover hints actually make a distinction between them.

Answer (score 16):

Since Typescript Version 4.1 you can do:

```js
type ExcludeMethods<T> = 
  { [K in keyof T as (T[K] extends Function ? never : K)]: T[K] }
```

Comment: The naming that you've used for this type makes much more sense to me than the accepted answer and also seems more in line with answering the original question. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

> Given a class, containing both properties and methods, I'd like to derive a type that just contains its properties.

From your example, it seems like you want the result to contain only fields ([as opposed to only properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4872444/1108891)). Here is a type that picks out the *fields* from an object or class instance.

```
type DataPropertyNames<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K;
}[keyof T];

type DataPropertiesOnly<T> = {
  [P in DataPropertyNames<T>]: T[P] extends object ? DTO<T[P]> : T[P]
};

export type DTO<T> = DataPropertiesOnly<T>;
```

I have used the acronym `DTO` to mean Data Transfer Object. Thank you to l00ser2410656 for [this playground demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=25&ssc=6&pln=25&pc=19#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAFATge0i0A5OBbCAZwB4AVAPigF4oBvAKCigG0BpKASwDsoBrCEGgBmUUgF0AXKLZioEAB7AIXACaEoAMQCuXAMbAOaHgH4oXCADcIKKFNYBuegF9m-QSPGP6oSLATJ0TAMiAHkuABsQMkoaBiZmJE4eeERUDGscfCJoyWkkWQUlVXU0ACMAKwh9KFMYUhCyBLFKKVIm5y8FMDQsKB9oOoaKaj9UwIyOUIioii9%20qAANEbimKBUtFARDLgB9PEIqqS4tPFLrR1WoOAs4DnC4UvCIAAouNAB3I5OzlABKKVKaDQTzgXEcTno9CewCg8gkg2ICxidEYUAA9Gi%20gALDjqQhYtBacIqKBnK48azoFCojGkqpwLQHTgw3FQPC4wjcADmNMx602BiMewOugAdB1IdCoCApEtYrzsaz8YTiXTyXIUFSFWddAymRwWep2YROVweUxaddbvdHhBxZdRY75M5IbojIRgXbwmguc8AETyP0AGlhv0cbq4Hqeou9vr9IGD0rDQA).

Comment: i so want this to work for me :-) thanks for posting. at the moment it ends up with an empty type when i try it. https://gist.github.com/raould/f523e235751f26a83c72154dde298bc6

Comment: @l00ser2410656 Nice catch. What you noticed was that each property is optional, not that the type is empty. I have changed the answer to remove the optional property marker `?` from the type definition. It will now work as you expect it to work.

Comment: Seems this doesn't work with either `Partial<DTO<T>>` or `DTO<Partial<T>>` 

Comment: @DrSensor What do you mean by "doesn't work." Here is an example of it working with `Partial<DTO<T>>`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAFATge0i0A5OBbCAZwB4AVAPigF4oBvAKCigG0BpKASwDsoBrCEGgBmUUgF0AXKLZioEAB7AIXACaEoAMQCuXAMbAOaHgH4oXCADcIKKFNYBuegF9m-QSPGP6oSLATJ0TAMiAHkuABsQMkoaBiZmJE4eeERUDGscfCJoyWkkWQUlVXU0ACMAKwh9KFMYUhCyBLFKKVIm5y8FMDQsKB9oOoaKaj9UwIyOUIioii9+qAANEbimKBUtFARDLgB9PEIqqS4tPFLrR1WoOAs4DnC4UvCIAAouNAB3I5OzlABKKVKaDQTzgXEcTno9CewCgAC8pEg4FgOHBwsRBsQFuQYnRGGsNlsjHsDropABGAAMHUhuiMhGBEAAdOE0ABzZ4AIlhHIANHDfvYgA

Answer (score 3):

```
export type DTO<T> = {
    [P in {
        [K in keyof T]: undefined extends T[K] ? never : T[K] extends (...args) => any ? never : K;
    }[keyof T]]: T[P] extends object ? DTO<T[P]> : T[P];
} &
    Partial<
        {
            [P in {
                [K in keyof T]: undefined extends T[K] ? K : never;
            }[keyof T]]: T[P] extends object ? DTO<T[P]> : T[P];
        }
    >;
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack overflow, try to accompany your code with an explanation to your code.

Comment: I get a headache just looking at this. A description would be interesting. Otherwise this should not be the top result

Comment: This is quite interesting. What is the purpose for `undefined extends T[K}`?

Comment: @DrSensor I believe it handles the case that the key is optional, otherwise typescript will complain `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'keyof T'`

e.g. `class Container { optional?: string }`

Answer (score 0):

```
export type Defined<T> = Exclude<T, undefined>;
        
export type NonFunctionPropertyNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K }[keyof T];
    
export type PartialModel<T extends Model> = {
  [K in NonFunctionPropertyNames<T>]?: Defined<T[K]>
};
```