# How to define Typescript Partial type to accept only properties

Tags: typescript

Using Typescript 3.7.  I have this class

```
class Thing {
  name: string;
  age: number;

  serialize() {}
}
```

Now in another method I want to declare that an argument is a partial of Thing, but should only include properties, not class.  So I want the accepted type to be

```
{name: string, age: number}
```

Is this possible? When I use `Partial<Thing>`, the method `serialize` is also accepted which I don't want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a type excluding instance methods from a class in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55479658/how-to-create-a-type-excluding-instance-methods-from-a-class-in-typescript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers to the [question this duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55479658/how-to-create-a-type-excluding-instance-methods-from-a-class-in-typescript) show how to use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) along with [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and [lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) to pull just properties matching a certain criterion out of an object.  Here's how I'd do it in your case:

```
type ExcludeFunctionProps<T> =
    Omit<T, { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends Function ? K : never }[keyof T]>

type AcceptedType = ExcludeFunctionProps<Thing>;
/*
type AcceptedType = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
*/
```

And you could use `Partial<AcceptedType>` if you want that.  A caveat here is that the compiler can't really tell the difference between *methods* and *function-valued properties*.  So if you had a class like

```
class Stuff {
    name: string = "";
    method() { }
    funcProp: () => void = () => console.log("oops");
}
```

then you'd be excluding both `method` as well as `funcProp` even though `funcProp` is a "field" or "property" and not a method:

```
type SomeStuff = ExcludeFunctionProps<Stuff>;
// type SomeStuff = {name: string}
```

So be warned.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqAWBLAdgc2gbwLAChr+mTAFsBTALmggBcAnFdAXmgCIVFqWBuXA6MVBUIBXYgCNStaMwAMPPAQiTEYEIgBepABQBKTNAC+uI3lzUAngAdS0AKIAPUMIAmpAGLDkwaogD2yAAVaX0sIAB5YAD5pXgIAeWIOCIAafQBtAGloFGgAa1JzXwAzOABdAFoAfkpYTNLoUntqUmRnGA8vH39oSugsymRSADdJQzT8wpLYUsjcMysbAEFgYFJLZudYBek7RxAXd09vP0Dg0IikNEj5AHoAKnnraGXV9dJN7eZsBXwiMkoaPQ0PI+AIhMhRBJaPITHcbnMcKBIDAAMrUYRFErfPh-ISAhg7FjcWL4MjUeC+Zy6fQmPhFI5BEKUamMaJDXyIZw7FnRYD+CC+ECkAB0IF8qC0LF8IQgLB0MIRFieKN8ZDRGJKzAcTlcHWO-kZ53VmOuuBuN2gSpsKrV6MxOwwuIBdAYJlwQA)

Comment: I think that gotcha is going to come back to bite me if I'm not careful.  Thank you!