# Typescript method of class generic type allows any

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Nearly there for one small exception that my constraint seems to still allow for any.
Who can tell me what I'm missing here.

Use case:

```js
    class A {
        public b(){}
        public c:number = 0;
        public d:any;
    };
```

Current implementation:

```js
    function methodOfClass<
        T extends { new (...args: any[]): any; } & Function, 
        M extends (this:T, ...args:any[]) => any = { 
            [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (this:T, ...args:any[]) => any 
                ? T[K] 
                : never
        }[keyof T]
    >(ctor:T, method:M, args?:Parameters<M>) : ReturnType<M> {
        return method.call(ctor, args ?? []);
    }
    
    const m0 = methodOfClass(A, A.prototype.b); // correct
    const m1 = methodOfClass(A, A.prototype.c); // correct 
    const m2 = methodOfClass(A, A.prototype.d); // incorrect :-(
```

Inspired by this thread I also managed the below, but can't find a suitable way to use it ?
[How to create a type excluding instance methods from a class in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55479658/how-to-create-a-type-excluding-instance-methods-from-a-class-in-typescript)

```js
    type Methods<T> = Omit<T, { 
        [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (this:T, ...args:any[]) => any 
            ? never 
            : K 
    }[keyof T]>;
    
    type M = Methods<A>; // correct
```

Comment: any is assignable to anything

Comment: as @RobertoZvjerković said, `any` can be anything.  It could be a method or it could be a property.  So this is expected behavior.  There is no error in your `methodOfClass` typings.  The only "error" is using `any` in class!

Comment: I totally agree that using any defies the purpose of having types in the first place, yes.

Answer (score 1):

#### `any` can be a `Function`

`any` can be anything, including a `Function`.  Your `methodOfClass` function has no way to know that you *intended* `d` to be a property.  It's perfectly fine for `d` to be a function.

```
const a = new A();
a.d = () => "hello world"; // no error because `() => string` is assignable to `any`
```

In other words, the result that you are seeing for `m2` is expected behavior and it is not "incorrect".  `any` means that `d` *can* be a function and it can be called with any arguments.  So this is fine too:

```
const m3 = methodOfClass(A, A.prototype.d, ["something", 999]);
```

Obviously there is huge potential for runtime errors by doing this.

The only solution here is to not use `any` on a class property!

#### Don't let `args` be optional

Unrelated to the issue of `any`, I highly recommend that you change the way that you are calling your methods in order to avoid runtime errors.  If the function requires arguments but you just use the default `[]` then you will have problems.

```
(ctor: T, method: M, ...args: Parameters<M>): ReturnType<M> {
    return method.call(ctor, ...args);
}
```

Using `...` allows you to pass nothing if no arguments are required, but requires you to pass all of the required arguments (as separate args to `methodOfClass` instead of as an array).

```
class E {
    public e(n: number): number {
        return n + 1;
    }
};

const m0 = methodOfClass(A, A.prototype.b); // this is still the same
console.log(m0); // undefined

const m3 = methodOfClass(E, E.prototype.e, 6); // but here we need a `number`
console.log(m3); // 7

const m4 = methodOfClass(E, E.prototype.e); // error because args missing
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/WP57ew)

Comment: spread/rest is a lot cleaner indeed, thanks for thinking with me.