# In Typescript, how do I set the type of an object to reflect a list of a class's properties?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

This example is made generic and simple, the underlying goal is more complicated but understanding how this would be done is important.

Say I have a class

```
class Foo {
  bar: string;
  baz: number;
  bob: any; // could be a function

  bad() {
    return true;
  };
}
```

and I have a function

```
const init = (options: InitOptions, bar?: string, baz?: number, bob?: any) => {
  const foo = new Foo();
  foo.bar = bar ?? options.fallbacks.bar;
  foo.baz = baz ?? options.fallbacks.baz;
  foo.bob = bob ?? options.fallbacks.bob;
}
```

How do I create the type InitOptions such that it acts like this

```
type InitOptions = {
  fallbacks = {
    bar: string;
    baz: number;
  }
}
```

but without having to repeat myself.  ex. `fallbacks` should be an object where each key is a property from `Foo`.

Comment: Just a note: I'm not sure if this is a typo or part of your code, but I believe you're missing a } in the last code example.

Comment: This looks like a typo: `const init(options: InitOptions, bar?: string, baz?: number) {`

Comment: You can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/WK8dDw), but it doesn't programmatically distinguish methods from function-valued properties.  If you had, say, `class Foo { a = () => 123; b() { return 123 }; }` , then `OmitKeysMatching<Foo, Function>` would omit both `a` and `b`.  If you're okay with this approach then I could write up an answer.  If not, please [edit] the question to show failing use cases.  Oh, and you should probably edit the code to be a [mre] with no typos (e.g., `const init(...)` is invalid syntax, `fallbacks =` is invalid syntax); you should test in an IDE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a type excluding instance methods from a class in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55479658/how-to-create-a-type-excluding-instance-methods-from-a-class-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use good old OO inheritance paradigm?

```
class Fooable {
  bar: string = '';
  baz: number = 0;
}

class Foo extends Fooable {
  bad() {
    return true;
  }
}

class InitOptions {
  fallbacks: Fooable = { bar: '', baz: 0 };
}

function init(options: InitOptions, bar?: string, baz?: number) {
  const foo = new Foo();

  foo.bar = bar ?? options.fallbacks.bar;
  foo.baz = baz ?? options.fallbacks.baz;

  console.log(`Initialized with bar: ${foo.bar}, baz: ${foo.baz}`);
}

init({ fallbacks: { bar: 'Hello', baz: 123 } });
init({ fallbacks: { bar: 'Hello', baz: 123 } }, 'World', 456);
```

When run with **ts-node** 10.2.1 it gets:

```
Initialized with bar: Hello, baz: 123
Initialized with bar: World, baz: 456
```

Comment: The main reason I was hoping for another solution to this is so that I could possibly use the type as a generic of the object being passed in.  But this is my current way I am doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it as easy as?

```js
class InitOptions 
{
  fallbacks: Foo;
}
```

Updated after clarification:

```js
{
  fallbacks: Pick<Foo, keyof Foo>;
}
```

Comment: No, because if the class has methods those are included as well.

Comment: The update still shows the method as an option, updating question to add method to class

Comment: Yes, `Pick` will pick methods too...

Comment: @TylerClendenin: Is there a particular reason why you don't want to include methods?
In any case, if that is an absolute requirement, you should say so in your question.

Comment: @MontanaBurr It was a part of the title that I specified that I wanted the class's properties

Comment: @TylerClendenin Yes, I understand that. But why grab just the properties when you can just grab the whole thing and disregard what you don't need?