# Pass dicitionary-style object parameter implementing T properties to class<T>

Tags: typescript, oop

I am using inheritance to initialize `class<T>`'s properties with  an `Object` implementing all `T` properties`{..}` passed to `constructor`

```
export default abstract class DatabaseObjectModel<T> extends JSONModel<T> {
  constructor(json: T) {
    super();
    this.fromJSON(json);
  }
}

export default abstract class JSONModel<T> extends ModelValidation {
  // abstract toJSON(): Object;
  // abstract fromJSON(json: Object): T;

  toJSON() {
    // Default toJSON
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this));
  }

  fromJSON(json: Object) {
    // For each key of json, assign value to this.key
    for (let key in json) {
      this[key] = json[key];
    }
  }
}
```

**Problem** is, when I initialize `DatabaseObjectModel`-inherited classes like this:

```
new ImplementingDatabaseObjectModel({
    id: randomUUID(),
    name: "MASTER",
    permissions: [],
    assignedRoles: undefined,
})
```

I get the following **error**:

```
Argument of type '{...}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ImplementingDatabaseObjectModel
```

How can I modify `DatabaseObjectModel<T>` `constructor` to accept an `Object` implementing all properties of `type T` but **not its instance**?

Answer (score 0):

Have found the solution here:

[How to create a type excluding instance methods from a class in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55479658/how-to-create-a-type-excluding-instance-methods-from-a-class-in-typescript)

```
export type DTO<T> = {
    [P in {
        [K in keyof T]: undefined extends T[K] ? never : T[K] extends (...args) => any ? never : K;
    }[keyof T]]: T[P] extends object ? DTO<T[P]> : T[P];
} &
    Partial<
        {
            [P in {
                [K in keyof T]: undefined extends T[K] ? K : never;
            }[keyof T]]: T[P] extends object ? DTO<T[P]> : T[P];
        }
    >;
```