# How to omit methods from a class type

Tags: typescript

Given the following class declaration, how to get a type that excludes the method `getSomething`? The example below gives an error because it expect the object to have the method `getSomething`

```ts
class Test {
    public readonly label: string = '';
    public constructor(opts?: Test) {
    Object.assign(this, opts);
    }

    public getSomething(): Array<number> {
        return [];
    }

}

const test: Test= new Test({label: 'label'}) // an error is thrown
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a type excluding instance methods from a class in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55479658/how-to-create-a-type-excluding-instance-methods-from-a-class-in-typescript)

Answer (score 2):

You can remove functions from a type, but this will unfortunately remove fields that are functions as well:

```
type OmitFunctions<T> = {
    [P in keyof T as T[P] extends Function ? never : P]: T[P]
}

class Test {
    public readonly label: string = '';
    public constructor(opts?: OmitFunctions<Test>) {
        Object.assign(this, opts);
    }

    public getSomething(): Array<number> {
        return [];
    }

}

const test: Test = new Test({ label: 'label' })
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useDefineForClassFields=true#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gtgS2AMQK4DsDGwEHt0DOAPACoB8UAvFAN4BQUjUA2gApQLpQDWEIuAMygkoAQwLC2AXSgQAHsAjoAJhLRYc+KAH4o6CADcIAJygAuKKykWS0ugF86dTABtxEkhALBaDJmFQAIxcETChjCFFlfBcQKDdAiBcLb2NOAHMqKABybIBuP0YA4NCoTHxU1GxcYwAKXDBgAm0LeCR1bDxCUi9gMgBKXyZh2ECAKwhsADp3BHT0WuAACwQCABooBqb+guHHQqhikLD0iGAAZVw4M5X0dNr+iwBBY2NRECJ0VDhE4wp6EZMCLAVDGLjMKS7Jj7fblQg+RTeGy9LL6ADuwl6tRo8VEiWSOQSSWyUHsgyAA)

You can create a type where you add back any function fields, but it would be a manual process:

```
type OmitFunctions<T, Exclude extends keyof T = never> = {
    [P in keyof T as T[P] extends Function ? P extends Exclude ? P: never : P]: T[P]
}


class Test {
    public readonly label: string = '';
    public readonly fn!: () => string;
    public constructor(opts?: OmitFunctions<Test, 'fn'>) {
        Object.assign(this, opts);
    }

    public getSomething(): Array<number> {
        return [];
    }

}

const test: Test = new Test({ label: 'label', fn: () => "" })
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&target=99&ts=4.7.0-dev.20220330#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gtgS2AMQK4DsDGwEHt0DOAPACoA0UAogB6YA2qAJtBNcBOowVANYQi4AZlBJQAvFHQQAbhABOAPnFQA3gCgomqAG0AClATpe-ISKgBDbiT0BdKK3aduaLDnxQA-FH0OOXKrQMzJ7eAFySMvJQ4bo24daxagC+aqn0llYQBMCqGlpgqABGdAiYUHIQ5oz4dCBQdOaFEHTh2XKGAObKAOTdANx5mgXFpeWV1ei1UILoAIThABQAlOJKbZ0DWlDDJWWY+G2o2LhyC7hgwAQe4fBILth4hKRZwBTdM90KK+pbWzCFACsINgAHQZBAddALYAACwQBAo50uS02WhSg22RV2UA6EGAAGVcHA8XD0B1luEAIJyOTmEBEdCoOBNRS5X5aCrAVByIzaGyozTo9H7Qg5djZeIvZRSADuIheCxU9UazXC3QaTTo3QoM0WKzESgARIaoEkVkA)

Answer (score 0):

`OmitProperties` of `ts-essentials` can be used

```
import { OmitProperties} from 'ts-essentials';

public constructor(opts?: OmitProperties<Test, Function>) {
    Object.assign(this, opts);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the built-in `Partial<T>` generic type as follows.

```
class Test {
  public readonly label: string = "";

  public constructor(opts?: Partial<Test>) {
    Object.assign(this, opts);
  }

  public getSomething(): Array<number> {
    return [];
  }
}

const test: Test = new Test({ label: "label" }); // runs without error
```